# flutter dart bigint vs num/double

Tags: flutter, dart, double, bigint

I got a simple question here with dart-flutter [:

BigInt is really helpful when we deal with large ints. But when we type BigNum or BigDouble, errors are displayed. So, here comes the question.

Is it safe to use large num or double in dart-flutter? When we try to do something with BigInt variable using int(not BigInt) methods, it actually doesn't work. So i wonder if those hazardous ideas could be raised even when we use double or num which is really large enough to be considered in context of BigInt class.

Hope some dart-flutter guru would give a cool answer for this question! Thanks in advance [:

Comment: Where did you find `BigNum` and/or `BigDouble`? It is not part of the Dart or Flutter SDK. Or do you mean by error that you cannot find these types?

Comment: Yup. Of course there is no such classes. What i wanted to say is that i wanted to know if there is any equivalent built-in classes of those kinds of concepts, and the error was `error: Undefined class 'BigDouble'.`, for sure! [:

Comment: One thing I want to add is that a `num` object does never exist in Dart since it is just a shared class for `int` and `double` to be used when you want to allow taking both a `int` and `double`. So you cannot create a `num` but must create either a `int` or `double`.

Comment: @tsitixe Thanks for the question, I have same needs as yours. Have you happened to find any alternatives to BigInt for decimal numbers?

Comment: @MehulPrajapati hello bro, u might use this package if you want to make sure of best calculation precision with double. i guess it can be an alternative way to deal with ints larger than dart limits. https://pub.dev/packages/decimal
in my case, i had to synchronize the result of double calculation with firestore, but the db had its own limit, so the way of mine was to divide the double into 4 divisions of int(ex. 123456789987654321.123456789987654321 => div0: 123456789, div1: 987654321, div2: 123456789, div3: 987654321), then reassemble them with decimal package later on in the app [:

Answer (score 1):

For decimal numbers please use [Decimal package](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal/example)

```
//normal division
print((0.5 / 894654).toString()); //5.588752746871976e-7

//using Decimal package
print(Decimal.pars((0.5 / 894654).toString())); // 0.0000005588752746871976
```